# push object to array react native

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, use-state, array-push

I need to get specific users who have the serviceClientID field in the firestore.

those that do, I insert it into the array and put it in my state chats (setChat).

but the problem is that only one user is entering my state and I have two users with this field.

why is only 1 entering and not 2?

code below:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async ({ uid }) => {
          const servicesCollection = await firestore()
            .collection('Providers')
            .doc(uid)
            .collection('ServiceHistory')
            .get();
          servicesCollection.docs.forEach(async item => {
            if (item.exists && item.data().serviceClientID) {
              const clientsCollection = await firestore()
                .collection('Clients')
                .doc(item.data().serviceClientID)
                .get();

              // if (item.data().serviceClientID === clientsCollection.id) {
              const values = {
                id: clientsCollection.id,
                name: clientsCollection.data().name.last,
                uid,
              };
              const arr = [];

              arr.push(values);
              // }
              console.log('arrayay', arr);

              setChats(arr);
            }
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause every loop you empty an array.
You have to get the {arr} out of the function. then you need to push the data inside.

```js
const firebaseFunc =  () => {
      let arr = [];

      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async ({ uid }) => {
        const servicesCollection = await firestore()
            .collection('Providers')
            .doc(uid)
            .collection('ServiceHistory')
            .get();
        servicesCollection.docs.forEach(async item => {
          if (item.exists && item.data().serviceClientID) {
            const clientsCollection = await firestore()
                .collection('Clients')
                .doc(item.data().serviceClientID)
                .get();
            arr.push({
              id: clientsCollection.id,
              name: clientsCollection.data().name.last,
              uid,
            });
          });
      });

      setChats(arr);
      console.log('arrayay', arr);
    }
```